# E-visa eligibility to enter Northern Cyprus

Tags: visas, e-visas, northern-cyprus

I have a valid US visa, I will be going to northern Cyprus.

Will having the Turkish e-visa allow me to enter Northern Cyprus?

Answer (score 2):

Both Turkey and North Cyprus consider the other to be fully independent countries so travel requirements for one are not relevant to the other. [The visa requirements for North Cyprus are outlined here.](https://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/) There are only 3 countries which require visas to enter, all of which require in-person applications. In short, US or Turkish Visas are not relevant for entry into Northern Cyprus.